# Passing javascript array tojava servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, servlets

I have found other question regarding on this, but still im having a problem,When i check `getParamerterValues`, its always return `null`, and i think im having trouble redirecting it to my controller.Bare with me, in new to web app.

```
arr = [];
$(document).on("click","#idhere",function(){
    $.post("servlet.html","ids="+arr+"",function(response){
    });
});
```

or is there something like converting array of javascript to JSON of array in JSP so i can pass it to my servlet?

```
 String arr [] = request.getParameterValues("ids");

if(arr != null){//this line doesnt return true even my array contains item}
```

Comment: your question title say you want to pass to servlet then why you are writting servlet.html?

Comment: I agree with the above question. However, I would also pose the question of if 'servlet.html' exists within the same directory.

Comment: servlet.html is the name of my java servlet(servlet.java)

Comment: Also servlet.java containes code that will redirect to jsp file

Comment: show your servlet code. check in browser network tab is your ajax call success or not.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
String arr [] = request.getParameterValues("arr");
```

to

```
String arr [] = request.getParameterValues("ids");
```

Comment: strill arr is null when i check on servlet sir

Comment: check your browser network tab `ids` has any data or not? and in your javascript code you have not initialized value to `arr = []` at all. check out.

Answer (score 1):

> Its always return null, and i think im having trouble redirecting it to my controller

I couldnt see any code to pass the values to the controller. In your jquery function , you have something like this `$.post("servlet.html","ids="+arr+"",function(response){`

It is not possible to post a value to the other html file from jsp. if you are trying to pass the values to the servlet.

try something like this ,

```
$(document).on("click","#idhere",function(){
    $.post("servletName","ids="+arr+"",function(response){
    });
});
```

**Note**: `servletName` refers to the url , mapped in your `web.xml` for the servlet you are trying to post the data.

Also make sure you `jquery function` is posting the data correctly to the controller through the browser console .

Comment: this is working `"servlet.html"` when i used in other case ,only if data is  JSON.stringify(array), $.post("servlet.html","ids="+JSON.stringify(array)+"",function(response)

Comment: $.post("servlet.html","data i passed here before is working",function(response) so i think this redirecting is not the issue

Comment: can you post , what you have inside `"servlet.html"` ?

Comment: sir,wai ill post it later

Answer (score 0):

As the examples below show, the post method wants an json object as the data parameter.

This should do the job

```
$.post("servlet.html",{"ids": arr.join()},function(response){
    });
```

> Examples: Example: Request the test.php page, but ignore the return
>   results.
>
> 1 $.post( "test.php" ); Example: Request the test.php page and send
>   some additional data along (while still ignoring the return results).
>
> 1 $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ); Example: Pass
>   arrays of data to the server (while still ignoring the return
>   results).
>
> 1 $.post( "test.php", { 'choices[]': [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } ); Example:
>   Send form data using ajax requests
>
> 1 $.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: test.php will work because php is a server side page but servlet.html wont work because it is a static page.

Comment: what servlet.html is depends on the server. When we are talking about tomcat and servlets servlet.html can an the public access point of the servlet.

Comment: how can you write doPost or doGet methods in html page

Comment: Are you sure OP has also configured web.xml like this?

Comment: Not sure, but OP has figured out that the parameter does't arrive, so I think the endpoint gets called.

Comment: then its wrong.We can not assume while answering.We have to answer as per OP's question.And from the post its clearly gives an idea that OP is calling an html page via ajax